# Cover a line segment randomly with smaller line segments

Tags: bioinformatics, geometric-probability, st.statistics, pr.probability, probability-distributions

Covering a circle randomly with arcs has been well studied in the past ([Geometric Probability - Solomon](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Geometric_Probability.html?id=tY8cAZFklIEC)).

But the problem when the circle is changed to a line segment doesn't seem to have been studied before.

I'd like to know if there's any work out there who already obtained the probability distribution of the number and the length of the connected line segments that you get when randomly covering a line segment with another set of shorter segments, which may all be of equal length or have some kind of distribution.

Thanks!

Comment: Erm... What's the difference between the circle and the line segment? You just have a small endpoint effect, which can shift the counts by $1$ here and there but I would have pretty hard time designing a meaningful problem in which either the answers would be essentially different, or ,at least, the reduction of one case to another would be non-trivial. 

Comment: Fedja, if you pick pairs of points (and if that carries little meaning, adjust the distribution so that nearby points are more likely to be chosen), and define the interval selected by order (or in the case of the circle, by the shorter arc), then I find it challenging to relate the line problem to a circle problem because the line problem "seems to avoid" a certain point on the circle.  Perhaps you can find an easy reduction that makes the circular form of the line problem give a nice solution to the line problem?  I don't see one.  Gerhard "Don't Ask Me About Reductions" Paseman, 2012.01.06

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is the idea that you take a line segment; randomly produce smaller line segments; keep going until you've covered the original segment? 

You're then asking how many you need? Do you include line segments that are entirely contained in the union of segments that you've already put down?

Please be more precise...

Comment: @Gerhard. A lot depends on *which* circle problem you want to relate it to. You can avoid not just one, but 100 points on the circle, if you choose so. My point was not that every interval problem reduces to the *classical* (uniform distribution, etc.) circle problem but merely that the circle is a much more natural domain for this covering business and that all standard results on the circle can be transferred to the interval setting without any trouble. Of course, if you create a *principally new* problem for an interval, you'll have to couple it with a new circle problem.  

Comment: @Anthony The problem I'm talking about is [DNA sequencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_sequencing)

Comment: That's a long and tangled article. Can you extract the precise math. question from it?

Comment: @fedja The problem is can be described like this: if smaller line segments are randomly picked from a longer line segment, what's the distribution of the number of connected "contigs" that consist of overlapping line segments and what's the distribution of the number of gaps? You can see Chapter 6 in in Solomon's Geometric Probability.

Comment: Also posted to MSE. In future, if you are going to post to both sites, **PLEASE** indicate this in your question. That way we avoid duplicated effort

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96297/cover-a-line-segment-randomly-with-smaller-line-segments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem can actually be solved using the exact same method as Chapter 4 of Solomon's geometric probability using the inclusion-exclusion principle in a similar fashion. A brief outline is available [here](http://li-tianyang.com/research/bioinformatics/single-contig-probability.pdf) (although it may contain small errors).